# ffmpeg: Send mp4 to fake webcam, "Invalid argument"

Tags: ffmpeg, webcam, mp4, v4l2

Trying to create a new fake webcam device (/dev/video2) and play a video on it so I can use it as a virtual webcam.

**Steps I took:**

```
sudo apt-get install v4l2loopback-dkms
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
sudo depmod -a

ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video2
```

**The error from the ffmpeg command:**

```
ioctl(VIDIOC_G_FMT): Invalid argument
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0
Conversion failed!
```

No idea what to do.